# Express Server Won't Resolve Promises on Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, express, network-programming

**Problem**

I have an express server running on MacOS Catalina 10.15 and is not resolving any internal promises. Normal APIs that don't require anything work and have been tested with Postman, but anything that requires a query of my database doesn't work. On postman it just infinitely loads the request and on my React Frontend, I get a "Proxy Error: could not proxy request (econnreset)". Note: This same express server has been tested on my Windows and Linux machine and it has worked perfectly so I believe it is a Mac issue.

My Server Code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Module dependencies;
const app = require('../app');
const http = require('http');
const { normalizePort, onListening } = require('./config');

// Get port from environment and store in Express;
const port = normalizePort('1234');
app.set('port', port);

// Create HTTP server;
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Event listener for HTTP server "error" event;
const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;

  const bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) { // Handle specific listen errors with friendly messages;
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

// Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces with event listeners and event handlers;
server.listen(port);
console.log(`server now listening on port: ${port}`)
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening(server));
```

Here is the app that is imported:

```
// Module dependencies;
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
require("dotenv").config();

// Our database instance;
const db = require("./database");

// Our apiRouter;
const apiRouter = require("./routes/index");

// Instantiate our express application;
const app = express();

// A helper function to create our app with configurations and middleware;
const configureApp = () => {
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(logger("dev"));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(compression());

  // Passport middleware
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  require("./bin/passport")(passport);

  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "*",
    })
  );

  // Mount our apiRouter;
  app.use("/api", apiRouter);
};


// Main function declaration;
const bootApp = async () => {
  await configureApp();
  //await seedDb();
  //db.sync();
};

// Main function invocation;
bootApp();

// Export our app, so that it can be imported in the www file;
module.exports = app;
```

I have tested my database credentials with pgadmin so that can't be the issue. In addition, my database has no restrictions on it and is open to all addresses. Here is the API that I was trying to request. I have sanitized it. By using console.log, I have determined that the const user await is never resolved.

```
//login
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(400, "Missing required fields");
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: "employee@example.com" } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new ErrorHandler(404, "Incorrect credentials");
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Do you think this could be the problem from networking issues? I have reset my network settings to default and have reinstalled the node_modules, npm, and node. I have installed node with homebrew if that can lead to any issues. This is primarily a mac issue as I never had this problem on my windows or linux machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Problem actually wasn't anything to do with express or the mac os settings.

I was trying to set up a new environment on MAC OS Catalina and was using Node JS version 14. My windows machine and linux machine both used Node JS version 13. Sequelize has reported issues of hanging API requests on Node JS version 14. That information is documented here:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158

Hope this helps anyone having this issue.